# Matplotlib don't show Float values on axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

`result` is pandas dataframe with float64 values on `Total Academic Expectations Score` and `Parent Response Rate`. 
It does make Plot but on x-axis instead of float numbers it shows 0s only.

**DataFrame looks like this:** (there are much more rows ofc)

|  | DBN | Total Academic Expectations Score | Parent Response Rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 01M015 | 8.2 | 0.71 |
| 0 | 01M019 | 7.7 | 0.92 |

```py
result['Total Academic Expectations Score'].groupby(result['Parent Response Rate']).plot(kind ='bar')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I've tried tight layout as shown but it was unsuccessful.

note: `Parent Response Rate` is 0 to 1 float, and `Total Academic Expectations Score` is 0 to 10 float

[image]

I want to show what is the mean of the Total Academic Expectations Score for the same Parent Response Rate

Comment: You should provide a minimal reproducible example, not a textual description of the data

Comment: For a same parent response rate, what do you want to show? The mean, the sum, other of total academic expectations score?

Comment: @Corralien updated (I want to see a mean of it) and had a exact logical problem in the code so I already fixed it thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
result.groupby('Parent Response Rate')['Total Academic Expectations Score'].mean().plot(kind='bar', rot=45)
```